# Ruby Regex: How to match pattern that follows another pattern?

Tags: ruby

I have ID numbers that should come after the text `ID:` so my file consists of

`ID: A1234`
`ID: A1235`
`ID: A1236`

etc. I want to match `/[A-Z]*[0-9]+/` but only if it comes after the characters `ID:`. How would I add that to the regular expression but not make it return ID: as part of the result? I just want it to match the regex that follows ID:, because at the end of the file I have numbers and it's returning them, but those aren't ID numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/ID:\s*([A-Z]*[0-9]+)/
```

the parentheses capture what's inside the parentheses, and then you can refer to it using backreferences.  If you post some code of how you're using the regex, I can try to add some more detail to show you how.